# Is there a phpMyAdmin for HTML5 local storage?

Tags: html, editor, phpmyadmin, local-storage

I'm wondering if there is a downloadable phpMyAdmin-like editor/interface for adding/editing/deleting data for creating your own HTML5 local data storage?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your site uses the local storage then in chrome, open your site and right click it. Go to inspect element. A tab will open up after the footer of your website. On that tab please click on storage. You will be able to view the database and tables . You can also write custom query there. Please let me know if it works for you , I can help you sending the snapshot.

In firefox you can download the addons called SQlite manager from the link below:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/

May this helps you